# Is 6 the default decimal digits of floating point in python format?

Tags: python, floating-point, format

I'm learning the format method in python and tried to convert 1 to a float by it.

```
"{:f}".format(1)
```

But why is the output `'1.000000'` instead of `'1.0'`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/string.html#formatspec) says for formatting with `f` “Displays the number as a fixed-point number. The default precision is 6.”

Note that not all Python implementations use the same format for floating-point. As the documentation [notes](https://docs.python.org/3.7/tutorial/floatingpoint.html), most modern machines use IEEE-754 floating-point arithmetic, and almost all platforms map Python `float` objects to IEEE-754 basic 64-bit binary format, but this is not guaranteed.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose this is the default output if you do not specify the number of decimals. Using the 3.6+ f-string format:

```
f'{1.123456789:f}'
'1.123457'

f'{1:.1f}'
'1.0'

f'{1.12345678901234567:.10f}'
'1.1234567890'
```

Now a whole other question is what is the precision of a floating point number, for example

```
f'1.1:.20f'
'1.10000000000000008882'
```

which seems to suggest a floating point gives up to 16 decimal accuracy. If you need more then you need to use the `Decimal` module [Decimal fixed point and floating point arithmetic](https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html)